# What is the difference between WindowResized, WindowSizeChanged, and VideoResize events in pygame?

Tags: python, events, pygame, resize, window-resize

I'd like to scale my sprites when the window gets larger or smaller, I'm not sure which event to watch for in my game loop.

According to the pygame [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#:%7E:text=WINDOWRESIZED%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Window%20got%20resized%0AWINDOWSIZECHANGED%20%20%20%20%20%20Window%20changed%20its%20size):

`VIDEORESIZE`:

> Description: sent when the user adjusts the window dimensions.
> Attributes: `size`, `w`, and `h` to give the new size.

The docs call it a "legacy" event and recommend using WINDOWEVENTs.

`WINDOWRESIZED`:

> Description: Window got resized.
> Attributes: `x`, `y`, and `window`.

`WINDOWSIZECHANGED`:

> Description: Window changed its size.
> Attributes: `x`, `y`, and `window`.

Is there any advantage to using one over the other? Is there any core difference between them?

---

I made a minimal example to view the events that get sent when I resize the window.

```python
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 900),pygame.RESIZABLE)
pygame.display.set_caption("Minimal Example")
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(2) #small fps so not too many events flood in
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT: running=False
        print(event) #output events that are sent
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Here's an example of some of the output:

```
<Event(32778-WindowResized {'x': 994, 'y': 661, 'window': None})> 
<Event(32779-WindowSizeChanged {'x': 994, 'y': 661, 'window': None})> 
<Event(32769-VideoResize {'size': (994, 661), 'w': 994, 'h': 661})> 
<Event(32778-WindowResized {'x': 994, 'y': 661, 'window': None})>
```

All event types give the same width and height values. The 'window' attribute doesn't seem to have any value.

If I resize with my mouse, `WindowResized` appears twice.
If I resize with my keyboard (like `⊞` + `→` for half-screen), all event types are still sent, and `WindowResized` only appears once, at the end.

Tutorials I've found online for resizing still all tend to use `VIDEORESIZE`, and I haven't been able to find articles, discussion threads, or documentation about what the difference is in these event types.
Does anyone know the inside code for these, and if it makes any difference using one or the other?

Answer (score 0):

The `WINDOWRESIZED` and `WINDOWSIZECHANGED` event are intended for [`pygame._sdl2.video.Window`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sdl2_video.html#pygame._sdl2.video.Window). You can have several windows and must know which window the event is coming from.

Comment: Okay thank you, so they give information about which window is being resized and VideoResize doesn't. What is the difference between WindowResized and WindowSizeChanged?